# Examples for coding against the PayPal API in .NET 2.0+?

Tags: .net, asp.net, paypal

Can anyone point me to a good introduction to coding against the paypal API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this article by Rick Strahl recently http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/PayPalIntegration/PayPalIntegration.asp.

Have not implemeted anything from it yet, Rick has quite a few articles around the web on ecommerce in aspnet, and he seems to show up everytime I'm searching for it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you start by downloading the SDK:

https://www.paypal.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_sdk-resource.html

The SDK includes the following:

- Client libraries that call PayPal APIs
- API documentation for SDK components
- Sample code for Website Payments Pro and various administrative APIs
- Testing console that can verify connectivity to PayPal and submit API calls

You may also want to take a look at [Encore Systems .NET* Class Library for PayPal SOAP API](http://paypal.encoresystems.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your needs are, but you might want to consider [Google Checkout](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samples/Google_Checkout_Sample_Code_NET.html).  [Joe Audette](http://www.joeaudette.com/paypal-sandbox-doesnt-work.aspx) was having considerable difficulty integrating PayPal.

I've [used](http://www.obtusesoft.com) Google Checkout and have had great success.  Note that you can go much, MUCH deeper with Google Checkout than the sample linked above.

---

EDIT: I didn't see Joe's updates.  Look like he did eventually get it working.