# Live Paypal Error

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I use PayPal in ASP.net and when I tested in sandbox everything was correct, but when I use the live part I'm getting this error:

> This payment cannot be completed and your account has not been charged. Please contact your merchant for more information.
>   We are not able to process your payment using your PayPal account at this time. Please return to the merchant's website and try using a different payment method (if available).

this is my webconfig

```
 <add key="token" value="*************************"/>
  <add key="paypalemail" value="*************@gmail.com"/>
  <add key="PayPalSubmitUrl" value="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"/>
  <add key="FailedURL" value="http://www.stockholmsbygg.net/Failed.aspx"/>
  <add key="SuccessURL" value="http://www.stockholmsbygg.net/FindOpenRequests.aspx"/>
  <add key="Notification" value="http://www.stockholmsbygg.net/Notification.aspx"/>
```

and redirect to Paypal

```
   public static string RedirectToPaypal(string invoiceNumber, string requestId, string userId, string customId, string itemName, string amount)
        {

            string redirecturl = "";
            redirecturl += "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paypalemail"].ToString();
            redirecturl += "&first_name=" + userId;
            redirecturl += "&item_name=" + itemName;
            redirecturl += "&amount=5.00";
            redirecturl += "&quantity=1";
            redirecturl += "&currency=SEK";
            redirecturl += "&invoice=" + invoiceNumber;
            redirecturl += "&custom=" + requestId;
            redirecturl += "&on0=" + HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
            redirecturl += "&return=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessURL"].ToString() + "?Type=ShowDetail";
            redirecturl += "&cancel_return=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedURL"].ToString();
            redirecturl += "&notify_url=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Notification"].ToString();
            return redirecturl;
        }
```

and this is everything that I check after returning from paypal to my address

```
if (Request.QueryString["cm"] != null)
                        {

                             const string authToken = "*********************************";
                             string txToken = Request.QueryString["tx"];
                             string query = "cmd=_notify-synch&tx=" + txToken + "&at=" + authToken;

                             //const string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
                           string strSandbox = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
                             var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSandbox);

                            req.Method = "POST";
                            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                             req.ContentLength = query.Length;


                             var streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
                           streamOut.Write(query);
                           streamOut.Close();
                           var streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                           string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
                             streamIn.Close();

                             var results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                             if (strResponse != "")
                             {
                                 var reader = new StringReader(strResponse);
                                 string line = reader.ReadLine();

                                 if (line == "SUCCESS")
                                 {

                                     while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                                     {
                                         results.Add(line.Split('=')[0], line.Split('=')[1]);

                                     }
                                     var userId = Convert.ToInt64(Session["UserID"]);
                                     var item = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["cm"]);
                                     context = new entities();
                                     var existUser = context.Payments.Where(u => u.UserID == userId).ToList();
                                     var existItem = existUser.Where(i => i.RequestID == item).ToList();
                                     var paypalInvoice = results["invoice"];
                                     var txn_id = results["txn_id"];
                                     var sameInvoice =
                                         existItem.Where(i => i.invoice== paypalInvoice).FirstOrDefault();
                                     if (sameInvoice != null)
                                     {
                                         var currentAmount = Request.QueryString["amt"];
                                         var dbAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(sameInvoice.Amount).ToString();
                                         var currentIp = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

                                         if (dbAmount != null)
                                         {
                                             if (currentAmount == dbAmount)
                                             {

                                                 if (currentIp == sameInvoice.IP)
                                                 {

                                                     sameInvoice.Status = true;
                                                     sameInvoice.PaypalTX = txn_id;
                                                     pnlSearch.Visible = false;
                                                     pnlShowDetail.Visible = true;
                                                     ShowDetail(Request.QueryString["cm"], true);
                                                     btnBack.Visible = false;
                                                     PrivateDetail.Visible = true;
                                                     interested.Visible = false;
                                                     context.SaveChanges();
                                                 }

                                             }
                                         }


                                     }

                                 }
                                 else if (line == "FAIL")
                                 {
                                     // Log for manual investigation
                                     Response.Write("Unable to retrive transaction detail");
                                 }
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                //unknown error
                                 Response.Write("ERROR");
                             }
                         }
```

What is the problem?
Also at the first time when testing I paid money but nothing happened. Invoice status wad still false while it should have turned to true since I paid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is an error 100% `RedirectToPaypal()`

There is no redirect to paypal. There is only `post` to that address with post parameters, not  `get` (redirect).

And this is logical because if you place all that sensitive data on the url, then is exposed to anyone that is ether proxy in the middle ether anything that keep the url with all that data.

For me if you make a redirect with that data, and not post, the paypal is not found anything about the account, because there are no post data, and thats why you get that error.

Comment: Thank you so much,so what should i do know !! please help me , what is your advice ? why it worked on sandbox ?

Comment: @user1615818 I do not know what is worked, but this is not. Can you give here how you make the first post on the paypal for the payment ?

Comment: @user1615818 Do you have read this manual ? https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf

Comment: The same exact codes which I have written. When I tested for the first time on Paypal's Live, everything worked just fine and the amount was withdrawn from my account too.  But the changes which should have been made in the post-payment, were not done. I attempted the test again and this time, no money would be withdrawn and the above error would be indicated.

Comment: @user1615818 Look, you have write here code that I do not know where you find it. Is simple - get the official paypal code and use it as is it. Get it from here https://cms.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code

Comment: @user1615818 here is one more http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19184/Use-of-the-PayPal-payment-system-in-ASP-NET  and one more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070/examples-for-coding-against-the-paypal-api-in-net-2-0   Stay on that, they work, the rest I do not what you try to do :)

Comment: thanks but i used PDT like this : https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216627 , can u help me what is wrong ?

Comment: @user1615818 The redirect is the main problem here `RedirectToPaypal` You also use the session on the rest code - there is the possibility the session to have been lost after the user return.

Comment: I'm so sorry,this is the last question,what is the best way to redirect to PayPal ? do you have any simple sample of PayPal that can help me ? , sorry I'm new on it,what should i instead of Session to check user !!? thank you so much

Comment: @user1615818 you are NOT make redirect. You create a form, and you post the data. On the paypal manual search for the "<form" and you see alot of examples. Also on this example look at the `<form id=payForm ...` http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19184/Use-of-the-PayPal-payment-system-in-ASP-NET

Comment: hello again, i used something like this is that correct ?               <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"/>  


 <input type="hidden" id="business" name="business" value="---------"/>  
 <input type="hidden" name="return" id="return" value="http://localhost:7440/FindOpenRequests.aspx?Type=ShowDetail"/>  
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name"  value=""/>  
 <input type="hidden" name="item_number" id="item_number" value="1"/>

Comment: and i fill value with jquery , is it correct ? what is your idea ?

Comment: After you fill them, you make post of them and if you have done right, it will work. Post - not ajax post.

Comment: yup i fill the with $.ajax , is there any problem for security ? because all parameter can change in Source of page

Comment: hi again,would u tell me is there any thing wrong in my code to security ?

Comment: @Erfanpj I do not have a full image of what you do. If you post the data, using ssl, then you do not have any security issues. In general you do not send any critical data, other than the email and the amount. so do not worry about that if its works.